# Rectangles showing on render

Tags: modeling

What is this rectangles showing when i render the model?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you tried it with recalculate normals (ctrl + n)?

Comment: maybe share this part of your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It looks like those are render tiles as that stamp is visible in the bottom of the image as well. I would try with different lighting setup to be sure. Probably it might have difference depending on which device you render